# Windows 2003 server failing to search on a network share when looking for "A word or phrase in the file"

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows

I've got a Windows 2003 terminal server and my users often search though remote text files for order numbers. We previously had a windows 2000 terminal server and the normal windows find dialog worked fine. Now with windows 2003 we always get zero results returned. Is there anything I need to tweak to get this working again?

Indexing services is enabled, everything else is on the default settings.

Comment: Which file extensions?

Comment: .edi - but it applies to anything not resisted with the indexer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to adjust the file types that are being indexed on the server.  Here's a [MS KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309173) that references the issue.

Comment: I agree. Blog entry here: http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2008/04/04/enabling-xp-and-windows-server-2003-to-search-all-files-types.aspx

Comment: The files are on a non indexed remote server which through me for a loop. But the solution works, thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution, even with indexing disabled I had to go to "indexing service" and enable "Index files with unknown extensions" and the files started showing up in the searches.

I used [Microsoft KB Article 209173: Using the "A word or phrase in the file" search criterion may not work](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309173) for reference.